# Selenium/Java: can I separate a Drag and Drop action in two actions belonging to two separate classes?

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop, automated-tests

I'm aware this is kind of a weird thing to want to do, but right now I'm building a test project, and I separated the several areas/containers of the application I'm testing in different classes, as a measure to keep organization. Therefore, if I want to drag an element from area A to area B, I've got to separate my D&D action in 2 methods, each belonging to a different class. I tried doing that in two ways:

Way 1:

```
//Class A
public void dragThumbnail(int startPosition) {
    Actions act = new Actions($(By.cssSelector("body")).getWrappedDriver());
    act.clickAndHold(getThumbnailFromPosition(startPosition)).build().perform();
}
//Class B
public void dropInDivider(int endPosition) {
    Actions act = new Actions($("body").getWrappedDriver());
    act.moveToElement(getDividerFromPosition().get(endPosition)).release().perform();
}
```

Way 2:

```
//Class A:
public void dragThumbnail(int startPosition) throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    int x = (getThumbnailFromPosition(startPosition)).getLocation().getX();
    int y = (getThumbnailFromPosition(startPosition)).getLocation().getY();
    robot.mouseMove(x,y);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
//Class B
public void dropInDivider(int endposition) throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    int x = getDividerFromPosition().get(endposition-1).getLocation().getX();
    int y = getDividerFromPosition().get(endposition-1).getLocation().getY();
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Evidently, none of them worked, because otherwise I wouldn't be here. I'm not too knowledgeable about Selenium Java yet, is anything wrong with my code, or is this just impossible/unfeasible to do, and I've just got to have everything in the same class?

I appreciate each and every input I might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows:

Step 1: Create a method to move the mouse cursor to points (x1, y1):

```
private void mouseMove(int destinationLocationX, int destinationLocationY) throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Point mousePosition;
    robot.mouseMove(destinationLocationX/2, destinationLocationY/2);
    mousePosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    while (mousePosition.x != destinationLocationX && mousePosition.y != destinationLocationY) {
        mousePosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        robot.mouseMove(destinationLocationX, destinationLocationY);
    }
}
```

Then, I created methods to find the exact center of each element:

```
private int getElementX(SelenideElement element) {
   return element.getLocation().x + element.getSize().getWidth()/2; }

private int getElementY(SelenideElement element) {
    return element.getLocation().y + element.getSize().getHeight()/2; }
```

Then, I created a generic drag and drop method, that I then used in several different other methods:

```
private void dndToCenterOfObject(SelenideElement source, SelenideElement target)
        throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.setAutoDelay(150);
    int sourceX = getElementX(source);
    int sourceY = getElementY(source);
    int targetX = getElementX(target);
    int targetY = getElementY(target);
    mouseMove(sourceX, sourceY);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    mouseMove(targetX, targetY);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a Mouse class which has a singleton initialization based on the driver. This means that each instance of WebDriver will return the same mouse object.

```
import java.util.HashMap;   
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Mouse {

    private Actions actions;
    private WebDriver driver;

    protected Mouse(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        actions = new Actions(driver);
    }

    private static HashMap<WebDriver, Mouse> mice = new HashMap<>();

    public static Mouse getMouse(WebDriver driver) {
        Mouse mouse = mice.get(driver);
        if (mouse == null) {
            mouse = new Mouse(driver);
            mice.put(driver, mouse);
        }
        return mouse;
    }

    public void clearActions() {
        actions = new Actions(driver);
    }

    public Actions addAction() {
        return actions;
    }

    public void perform() {
        actions.build().perform();
    }
}
```

Use this mouse object to add operation in each class. Note here that we are not building or performing the operation here. We are adding the operation to the Actions class. Then in the execution flow class we will perform the operations as a sequence.

```
public class A {
    public void dragThumbnail(int startPosition) {
        Mouse.getMouse(driver).addAction().clickAndHold(getThumbnailFromPosition(startPosition));
    }
}

public class B {
    public void dropInDivider(int endPosition) {
        Mouse.getMouse(driver).addAction().moveToElement(getDividerFromPosition().get(endPosition));
    }
}
```

Then call the below sequence to get the operation executed as a whole in

```
public class Test {
    public void executeTest() {
        // Get the mouse
        Mouse mouse = Mouse.getMouse(driver);
        // Clear previous mouse operations saved (if any)
        mouse.clearActions();
        // Add the operation in class A
        a.dragThumbnail(startPosition);
        // Add the operation in class B
        b.dropInDivider(endPosition);
        // Perform the operation now
        mouse.perform();
    }
}
```